# Using 'BasicButtonUI' to implement a relatively simple GUI - is that the correct approach?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons, each with a relatively simple GUI (or at least so I though):

[image]

The button is halved by a a diagonal line and a space for two numbers received as input.

I've been trying to implement it using `BasicButtonUI` but facing difficulties. I'm wondering if that's the correct tool to the job, or maybe as a newbie to Swing I'm missing a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Hmm. trimming that image would certainly help. Does the slash need to be left-top to right-bottom? Would `2\7` (all on one line) fit the requirement? Why does the button look like that? What does it mean? BTW - you might just create an icon with the correct appearance..

Comment: The line direction does not matter. what I'm trying to do here (and maybe taking the wrong approach) is to draw a "Kakuro" board.

Comment: I would use the interface Icon, which allows to paint all what you need. This approach has one disadvantage: some Button UIs provide an extra space betwen Icon and Button border

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy *"I would use the interface Icon"* That seems like a good approach for this requirement.